# POST JSON array to ASP.NET WebMethod

Tags: asp.net, json

I have a script which returns a data array in JSON as per below.

```
[
    {"ItemID":"10319","ItemCode":"ITEM-010318","Qty":"1","custRef":"12 - Mitsubishi Fighter FK61F"},
    {"ItemID":"10933","ItemCode":"ITEM-010932","Qty":"1","custRef":"12 - Mitsubishi Fighter FK61F"},{"ItemID":"10537","ItemCode":"ITEM-010536","Qty":"1","custRef":"12 - Mitsubishi Fighter FK61F"},
    {"ItemID":"14863","ItemCode":"ITEM-014862","Qty":"1","custRef":"12 - Mitsubishi Fighter FK61F"},
    {"ItemID":"14864","ItemCode":"ITEM-014863","Qty":"1","custRef":"12 - Mitsubishi Fighter FK61F"}
]
```

This data is stored in a variable called `cartData`

I then push the data to my WebMethod via AJAX, as follows

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "OrderFormServices.asmx/AddItemsToCart",
    data: JSON.stringify(cartData),
    dataType: "json"

});
```

My web method looks like this

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void AddItemsToCart(string [] itemID, string [] itemCode, string [] Qty, string [] custRef)
```

However when I try and POST the data, I get an error on the console which I can't make head or tail of! Can anyone shed some light on it?

```
Type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
[System.Object, mscorlib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'
is not supported for deserialization of an array.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method expects an array for each field.
So, either you change method to be something like:

```
public void AddItemsToCart(CartItem[] items)
```

Where CartItem is class with all these fields.

OR

Edit the js to pass as the web method expects like:

```
var data   = {
itemID : [],
itemCode:[],
Qty:[],
custRef:[]};
//here fill all array with each one of the items in the json array.
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "OrderFormServices.asmx/AddItemsToCart",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json"

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've edited as per your second suggestion and I'm now using 
                                `cartData.push({
                                    'itemID': itemIdVal,
                                    'itemCode': itemCodeVal,
                                    'qty': qtyVal,
                                    'custRef': custRefVal
                                });`  however this doesn't seem to be working - cartData.push is not a function?

Comment: no this wouldnt work, it will work like this:
cartData.push({ 'itemID': [itemIdVal], 'itemCode': [itemCodeVal], 'qty': [qtyVal], 'custRef': [custRefVal] });
Also be sure the param names are the same Case as the web method, for exmaple: Qty.

Comment: I get `cartData.push` is not a function?

Comment: It should be since its an array